# How to generate a random url safe string with Elixir

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I need to be able to generate random url safe strings so I could use those in links (like in an activation link sent to a user's email), so how can I generate it? Is there a way to do that only with Elixir or I'd have to use some library?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

What you can do instead is to generate a Base64-encoded string to be used as a confirmation token. This confirmation token will then be saved to your DB and passed as params to the activation link. Your activation url would look something like:

```
activation_url(MyApp.Endpoint, :confirm, confirm_id: confirm_id)
```

The above url helper assumes you have a `MyApp.ActivationController` and a `confirm/2` action in that controller. To generate the `confirm_id`, you could do:

```
def random_string(length) do
  :crypto.strong_rand_bytes(length) |> Base.url_encode64 |> binary_part(0, length)
end

# random_string(64)
```

In your `MyApp.ActivationController.confirm/2`, you could have code lik:

```
def confirm(conn, %{"confirm_id" => confirm_id}) do
  user = Repo.get_by(User, confirm_id: confirm_id)
  User.confirm(user)
  conn
  |> put_flash(:info, "Account confirmed!")
  |> redirect(to: "/")
end
```

Comment: Will the result of `random_string/1` be url safe?

Comment: I updated the answer to use the url-safe Base64 version.

Comment: Side note: you often want a target number of random bits rather than string length, e.g. session tokens should be at least 256 bit (32 bytes). To accomplish this, the binary_part() call should be omitted, at which point length will be the entropy of the generated key in bytes.

Answer (score 14):

You can easily define a module to do this. In this example, `@chars` determines what characters appear in your generated strings.

```
defmodule StringGenerator do
  @chars "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" |> String.split("")

  def string_of_length(length) do
    Enum.reduce((1..length), [], fn (_i, acc) ->
      [Enum.random(@chars) | acc]
    end) |> Enum.join("")
  end
end

StringGenerator.string_of_length(3) # => "YCZ"
```

Comment: Note that `@chars` also contains the empty string which means that the generated string may be shorter than `length`. To get only strings of one character use `String.split("", trim: true)`.

Comment: Thanks for this. Think you could alternatively just use `String.codepoints` instead of `String.split`. Also could be a bit cleaner using `map`, fwiw: `1..length |> Enum.map(fn _i -> Enum.random(@chars) end) |> Enum.join("")`.

Answer (score 6):

As noted in @JimGray's comment, your specification should really be in terms of the amount of entropy you want to represent by the random URL safe strings. Something along the lines of "I need N bits" because someone told you to use N bits, or "I want to avoid repeat in N strings and I can accept a risk of 1 in n of a collision". Either way, it's directly about entropy and only indirectly about string length.

For example, be sure that if you use a solution like @Gjaldon' answer you understand even though 512 bits of randomness is used, the amount of entropy for the actual string generated by `random_string(64)` is 320 bits. Whether that's sufficient is of course dependent on your scenario, which as noted above is probably best expressed as, for example, "I need a million strings with no more than a 1 in a trillion risk of repeat", in which case 320 bits is gross overkill as you'd only need 79.

If you want more control and understanding of generating random strings, look at [EntropyString](https://github.com/EntropyString/Elixir). With that library, you could do something like the following to get a string with 256 bits of entropy:

```
iex> defmodule Id, do: use EntropyString, charset: charset64
iex> Id.token
"ziKYK7t5LzVYn5XiJ_jYh30KxCCsLorRXqLwwEnZYHJ"
```

Or if you realize a million strings with a repeat risk of 1 in a trillion is
sufficient, you could set up your Id generation like:

```
iex> defmodule Id do
...>   use EntropyString, charset: charset64
...>   @bits entropy_bits(1.0e6, 1.0e12)
...>   def random, do: Id.random_string(@bits)
...> end
iex> Id.random
"FhlGVXOaXV9f3f"
```

Either way, control and understanding are nice things to have.